# Calculating a percentage of the variable price in PHP Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, percentage

I have a pricing matrix where a shopper can choose to pay of the cost over a period. I need to display this per month price under the full price in Opencart. I have managed to get a formula to half work, but as soon as I use a variable in the calculation it does not work.

I have this calculation, which works correctly when using actual numbers.
9.4 is the percentage of the price(1799)

```
<?php 
$mobi_price = (9.4 / 100) * 1799;
echo $mobi_price;
 ?>
```

The result is 169.10

What I need is for the price to be a variable i.e. not 1799 but $price, so that ir differs for each product.
However when I use the function like:

```
<?php 
$mobi_price = (9.4 / 100) * $price;
echo $mobi_price;
?>
```

The result is 0 and should be 169.10.
Any Ideas?

Comment: If the product of multiplication is 0 either or both sides are 0, your left side are constants (also good idea to put 0.094 instead of calculating each time) so what does that mean?

Comment: Probably `$price` is 0 (in your example code, you don't have a `$price` variable. @nevermind In php you can multiply the integer times of a string (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: In some cases also need to round of the answer echo $mobi_price;  from say R75.106 to R75.11. Help!

Comment: I do have a price variable. Here is the extract code of the price variable in the file.
___________________________________________________
      <div class="price"><?php echo $text_price; ?>
        <?php if (!$special) { ?>  
  <?php echo $price; ?>  
  <?php } else { ?>
 my calculation later in the file_________________________________________________________________________   the 790 below needs to be avariable.   
From <span style="color:#36a1c0">R<?php 

$mobi_price = (9.4 / 100) * 790;
echo $mobi_price;

?> </span>per month <br /><br />

Comment: e.g. [link}http://sassychic.co.za/oc2/a-z-designers/albertus-swanepoel/albertus-swanepoel-a-line-dress . The price product price and blow that is a mobicred price which is the calculation I need to make in php.